# Boost serialization in multiple linked libs?

Tags: c++, boost

I have a c++ project that links to two compiled libs. The libs are based on the same code that I have modified to run concurrently. However, both of these libs use `boost::serialization`, and so both of them have the following functions:

.h

```
 friend class boost::serialization::access;

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
        boost::serialization::split_member(ar, *this, version);
    }

    template<class Archive>
    void save(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version) const;

    template<class Archive>
    void load(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version);
```

When I try to compile the project with both the libs linked, I get:

```
d:\include\mMapPoint.h(190): error C2995: 'void boost::serialization::serialize(Archive &,cv::Mat &,const unsigned int)': function template has already been defined
d:\include\MapPoint.h(192): note: see declaration of 'boost::serialization::serialize'
d:\include\mMapPoint.h(207): error C2995: 'void boost::serialization::serialize(Archive &,cv::KeyPoint &,const unsigned int)': function template has already been defined
d:\include\MapPoint.h(199): note: see declaration of 'boost::serialization::serialize'
d:\include\mMapPoint.h(227): error C2995: 'void boost::serialization::save(Archive &,const cv::Mat &,const unsigned int)': function template has already been defined
d:\include\MapPoint.h(216): note: see declaration of 'boost::serialization::save'
d:\include\mMapPoint.h(245): error C2995: 'void boost::serialization::load(Archive &,cv::Mat &,const unsigned int)': function template has already been defined
d:\include\MapPoint.h(233): note: see declaration of 'boost::serialization::load'
```

The lines mentioned in `mMapPoint.h` are:

```
BOOST_SERIALIZATION_SPLIT_FREE(::cv::Mat)  //line 190

namespace boost {
namespace serialization {

/*** CV mKeyFrame ***/
template<class Archive>
void serialize(Archive & ar, cv::KeyPoint & kf, const unsigned int version)
{
  ar & kf.angle;
  ar & kf.class_id;
  ar & kf.octave;
  ar & kf.response; 
  ar & kf.response; 
  ar & kf.pt.x; 
  ar & kf.pt.y; 

} //line 207



/*** Mat ***/
/** Serialization support for cv::Mat */
template<class Archive>
void save(Archive & ar, const ::cv::Mat& m, const unsigned int version)
{
  size_t elem_size = m.elemSize();
  size_t elem_type = m.type();

  ar & m.cols;
  ar & m.rows;
  ar & elem_size;
  ar & elem_type;

  const size_t data_size = m.cols * m.rows * elem_size;

  ar & boost::serialization::make_array(m.ptr(), data_size);
}//line 227

/** Serialization support for cv::Mat */
template<class Archive>
void load(Archive & ar, ::cv::Mat& m, const unsigned int version)
{
  int cols, rows;
  size_t elem_size, elem_type;

  ar & cols;
  ar & rows;
  ar & elem_size;
  ar & elem_type;

  m.create(rows, cols, elem_type);  
  size_t data_size = m.cols * m.rows * elem_size;

  ar & boost::serialization::make_array(m.ptr(), data_size);
}//line 245
```

I assume this is because the names match in both the libs.

I have tried renaming these functions in one of the libs (to `msave`, `mload` and `mserialize`), but then a get a boost error:

`\boost/serialization/split_free.hpp(58): error C2672: 'load': no matching overloaded function found`

How can I run two libraries that both call these boost functions, concurrently? Thank you.

Comment: You have posted member function templates `serialize`, `load` and `save` of your own class(es). Leave them alone, they are not related to freestanding function templates from `boost::serialization` namespace which seem to trigger your error. It looks like your code somehow manages to `#include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>` twice in the same file despite include guards.

Comment: C2995 normally have this form: **filename1(line1)**: error C2995: ... **filename2(line2)** : see declaration of ... Please post full unedited error messages here, together with the lines they reference.

Comment: Thank you, I have added the full error, and the lines that are mentioned.

Comment: Where are the "see declaration of" lines?

Comment: Anyway it looks like mMapPoint.h lacks proper include guards.

Comment: lines added. `mMapPoint.h` is from one lib, `MapPoint.h` from the other. What should the include guards be?

Comment: Please google "include guards" before attempting to write any C or C++ code. Anyway the problem is not with include guards. The problem is with a library copying code from another library without so much as changing class names or namespaces. Naturally you cannot expect to be able to use these libraries together. If they share code, extract it to a third library.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I have changed the namespaces and class names in one of the libs, but it seems to make no difference.

Comment: You did not change them correctly. Why are you doung this anyway? Copying and pasting code is not solid software engineering and you would be laughed out of any code review for doing this. At any rate, this question is a moving target, it lacks a [mcve] and I'm voting to close it.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: If your issue cannot be resolved by a rebuild of your app, you should try declaring your template functions `serialize` `save` and `load` explicitly `inline`, and rebuild the libraries.  But... this really looks like a precompiled header issue.